# Finite State Machine - Does each state have to be represented by a case in the switch statement?

Tags: c++

[image: Finite State Machine]

Can this Finite State Machine be put into 4 cases? Or can this only be done with 3 cases since State D is not directly linked to State A with a certain bit.

```
while (true) {
    int bit2;
    if (state != D) {
        cout << "Enter a bit (1/0): ";
        int bit;
        cin >> bit;
        bit2 = bit;
    }

        switch (state) {
        case A:
            if (bit2 == 1) { state = B; }
            break;
        case B:
            if (bit2 == 0) { state = C; }
            break;
        case C:
            if (bit2 == 0) { state = D; }
            else { state = B; }
            break;
        case D:
            cout << "Done!" << endl;
            state = A;
            break;

    } 
} 


return 0;
```

This is the code I used, and it works perfectly fine. Was just wondering if I have to address "State D"

Comment: A switch statement is not the only way to represent a state machine, so in the strictest sense the literal answer to your to level question is no. (Its a little misleading). As to Why don't you try your idea? If you have tried it post your code. Pepole are more likely to want to help if they can see you are trying to find the answer yourself, and not just hoping that someone else knows.

Comment: You do have to address state D. What you have implies a transition directly from C to A, and you're never in state D for any iteration.

Comment: The beauty of the state machines and their *uniform* representation, is that they are strictly formal, making it easy to make assertions and prove the behavior. So stick with the uniformity and formality as long as you can.

Comment: The issue I have is, if I create "case D," it loops back to the top where I have to insert a 4th bit, which is not needed. Is it possible to reference state D without creating that 4th case?

Comment: @JimLee123 you can put the prompt in a condition `if (state != D)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hi, I posted a revised edition. Thank you for your "if" suggestion. Can you help me take a peek, and see if my edited version is plausible?

Comment: @JimLee123 I was thinking more like `int bit; if (state != D) { cout << "Enter a bit (1/0): "; cin >> bit; }` but that works too.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Many thanks. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you tagged this `C` when you have `C++` code? C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @DavidBowling thanks for catching that as well. I was just rolling back to keep the image that was unnecessarily removed.

Answer (score 4):

A naive implementation without boolean algebra taken into consideration might yield a `switch` statement that looks something like this:

```cpp
char next(char state, int path) {
    switch (state) {
        case 'A': return path == 1 ? 'B' : 'A';
        case 'B': return path == 0 ? 'C' : 'B';
        case 'C': return path == 1 ? 'B' : 'D';
        case 'D':
        default: return 'A';
    }
}
```

If you notice patterns like how a `path` of `1` leads to `B` except in case the case of `D` or in the indeterminate case, you can use less branches to achieve the same logic, so the short answer is no, you don't necessarily need 4 cases to handle 4 state transitions.

#### Longer answer (Digital Logic Design Approach)

Let's make a [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to minimize the number of logical operations. The first two bits `SS` can represent the state:

| state | MSB | LSB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| D | 1 | 1 |

Which we can achieve with:

```
SS = state - 'A';
```

Here is the K-map for the given state machine:

| <sub>path</sub> \ <sup>SS</sup> | 00 | 01 | 11 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00 | 10 | 00 | 11 |
| 1 | 01 | 01 | 00 | 01 |

This gives us the following sums of minterms for each bit of the next state:

```
MSB = path == 0 && (SS == 1 || SS == 2)
LSB = (path == 1 && (SS & 2) == 0) || SS == 2
```

Putting that all together, that leaves us with the following implementation:

```cpp
char next(char state, int path) {
    int SS = state - 'A';
    int MSB = path == 0 && (SS == 1 || SS == 2);
    int LSB = (path == 1 && (SS & 2) == 0) || SS == 2;

    return 'A' + ((MSB << 1) | LSB);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.